# How to draw in a responsive way in matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I was able to finalize a logo animation, the logo is built with different shapes.

here you can see the final result > [codepen link](https://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/zYwrrQq)

```
 // create a renderer
 var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      pixelRatio: 2,
      background: 'transparent',
      wireframes: false,
    }
 });

var rectangleA = Bodies.rectangle(19, 66, 38, 57, {
  render: {
    fillStyle: '#D1421F',
    lineWidth: 0
  }
});
```

but I don't know how to draw(make) it responsive?
not the canvas itself (i can do this with css), but the actual logo and the shapes that compose it.

basically, I would like that the logo will be always aligned in the center and it will take always 90% of the width of the viewport.

I know that in matter.js you need to write x,y numbers in pixel from the top-left corner for the bodies, but I am wondering how to deal with alignment in the center on the viewport and how to make it responsive (so the shapes will take always a % of the viewport).

I hope that my question/doubt is clear, maybe an image will explain better.

[image]

Could somebody point me to the right direction?

I am approaching the canvas world while I am studying matterjs, so any recommendation would be great!

Comment: Get the viewport's width, `x` is 10% of that width, and the logo's width is 80%...

Comment: the problem is that the logo is not just one element, but it is composed by 17 different shapes (matterjs Bodies), for this reason, I am not sure the best way to deal with this.
I already take the viewport's width and height, in order to make the canvas full-screen, but I am not sure how to deal with the dimension of the singular shapes (bodies).

Comment: You might check out [`render.bounds`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Render.html#property_bounds) where you can specify the bounding box you want to zoom in to show.